# How to detect intervals between keydowns in plain js

Tags: javascript

I have tried to detect the interval between keydowns on a div with this:

```
window.onload = function() {
var p = document.getElementById('input');
    p.addEventListener('keydown', function() {

        if (document.querySelector('.rps')) {
            p.removeAttribute('class')
            clearInterval('me')
        }

        if (!document.querySelector('.rps')) {
            p.setAttribute('class', 'rps')
            var me = setInterval('interval()', 10)
        }

    }, false)

}
var z = 0;
function interval() {
    z += 1
document.getElementById('isp').innerHTML = z;
}
```

**HTML:**

Test

The problem is , this will start the `interval()` on the first key press, but it will not remove the class `rps` which is required to determine whether to start or end the `setInterval`.

The solution should be in plain JS - and will work on more than one keypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `setInterval`. That is for doing something every `n` milliseconds.

You only want to do something when a key is pressed.

Bind a `keydown` event handler to the environment (or just to the element you are interested in if you want to limit it).

Inside that handler, create a `new Date()` and store it in a local variable.

In a particular variable from outside the scope of the event handler exists: Compare the times of them. (This will happen for every keydown except the first).

Copy the value of the local variable over the value of the one from the wider scope.

```js
function createHandler() {
  var last_keydown_time;
  
  function keydown_handler(event) {
    var this_keydown_time = new Date();
    if (last_keydown_time) {
      console.log(this_keydown_time - last_keydown_time);
    }
    last_keydown_time = this_keydown_time;
  }
  
  return keydown_handler;
}

addEventListener('keydown', createHandler());
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for telling me that `setInterval` should not be used for timing.

Comment: It shouldn't be used for *measuring* time.